# How can I actively remove duplicates from being input into a text file on a Flask server?

Tags: python, flask, text, duplicates

I am currently attempting to prevent duplicate names from being added to this text file, as data is input from POSTs to the server. My issue is that I only know how to remove duplicates from files that have already been closed - not files that are being actively added to. Here's the block of code below that I'm referring to:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods =['POST'])
def post():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.data)
            datastr = str(request.data)
            dataclean = datastr[1:].replace('\\r', '').strip("'").replace('\\n','\n')
            with open("PLAYERGATHERDATA.txt", "a") as SERVERDATA:
                SERVERDATA.write(dataclean)
            return 'FINISHED'
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port="8000")
```

So I would normally remove duplicates this way:

```
DATADIR = "C:\Users\Documents\PLAYERGATHERDATA.txt" 
fRAW = open(DATADIR, "rt")
fCLEAN = open("CLEAN.txt", "wt") 
line_seen = set() #Duplicate set check
for line in fRAW: 
    if line not in line_seen:
        fCLEAN.write(line.replace(' ', '_'))
        line_seen.add(line)
```

I would assume that after cleaning up the data with `dataclean = datastr[1:].replace('\\r', '').strip("'").replace('\\n','\n')`, that I would then remove duplicates from the incoming message. (These are 12 character names with newlines at the end), would I have to close the text file in order to remove duplicates, and then reopen the text file? Is there a better way of doing this that would make the program a bit cleaner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - here's the whole block:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

line_seen = set()

@app.route('/', methods =['POST'])
def post():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.data)
            datastr = str(request.data)
            dataclean = datastr[1:].replace('\\r', '').strip("'").replace('\\n','\n')
            with open("TempINPUT.txt", "wt") as SERVERDATARAW:
                SERVERDATARAW.write(dataclean)
            SERVERDATARAW.close()
            SERVERDATARAW = open("TempINPUT.txt", "rt")
            with open("PLAYERGATHERDATA.txt", "a") as SERVERDATA:
                for line in SERVERDATARAW: 
                    if line not in line_seen:
                        SERVERDATA.write(line)
                        line_seen.add(line)   
            return 'FINISHED'
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port="8000")
```